# number of questionnaires and sample size

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, experiment-design, survey, descriptive-statistics

Is there any correlation between number of questionnaires used in a study and the sample size in order to obtain accurate measurement?

Comment: Could you explain the distinction between "number of questionnaires" and "sample size"? Describing the context might help.

Comment: In a study, there are multiple dependent var that I plan to measure, hence the application of multiple survey instruments (or questionnaires) using quantitative method design. I would like to know if 60 participants are sufficient to obtain accurate results, or is there a way to calculate the sample size based on the number of instruments applied? Thanks

Comment: It's still difficult to tell.  Are all instruments given to all participants? How are we to say anything about accuracy without knowing the details of those instruments and the variability of the responses to them?  As it stands, your question is so abstract that it must be interpreted very broadly as "how do I determine sample sizes for a survey"? As I'm sure you know, there is a huge literature on that subject, suggesting our format would not be suitable for posting an answer until this question can be considerably narrowed in its focus and details.

Comment: Assuming all the instruments have been validated in previous research studies and have high reliability. I am not asking how to find sample size for my study (which I can obtain using a G*Power analysis). My question is straight forward: Do the number of instruments used in a study dictate the sample size? I hope this question is more concise now. Thanks

Comment: If you are still interested in this question, please add extra information/clarifications as an edit to the post! We want posts to be complete, self-contained, and comments are easily overseen ...